# How do I add Add text below font awesome icon Links?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome, blogger

I am trying to add some text under font-awesome Icons in my Blogger template. Here is the image of what I want to achieve

[image of Look I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVYlh.png)

But I have managed to achieve this till now

[image of progress till now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PePsP.png)

How to I add clicable link under each icon as shown in the second image?
As I am a newbie, it would be a huge help if you can also help me out with the font family and its styling.

p.s. I am using a custom template on blospot hosted blog.
I have tried out following code:

```css
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>

.sidebar-social {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-social ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

.sidebar-social li {
 text-align: center;
    width: 31.9%;
    margin-bottom: 3px!important;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.sidebar-social i {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
 width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;

    color: #444444;
}

.sidebar-social a i.fa-facebook:hover { color: #FF0000; }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-twitter:hover { color:#00ABE3 }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-instagram:hover { color:#FFD400 }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-pinterest:hover { color:#FF0000 }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-google-plus:hover { color:#cb2027 }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-flickr:hover { color:#FF57AE }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-500px:hover { color:#00ABE3 }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-youtube:hover { color:#FF1F25 }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-behance:hover { color:#FF57AE }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-social">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="URL-HERE" title="Facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Google Plus" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
</li>
        
<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
</li>
        
<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Pinterest" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
</li>
        
<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Instagram" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
</li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Behance" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a> 
</li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="flickr" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a>
</li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="YouTube" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
</li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="500px" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-500px"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just add a `span` tag in your `a` tag that way it would be possible to apply different styles (like `margin`, `color`) on your text without affecting the `font-awesome` icons.

```css
.sidebar-social {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-social ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

.sidebar-social li {
   text-align: center;
    width: 31.9%;
    margin-bottom: 3px!important;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding:0;
}

.sidebar-social i {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
 width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #444444;
  margin-top:0;
  padding-top:5px;
}
.sidebar-social a{
  text-decoration:none;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.sidebar-social a span{
  color:black;
  font-size:10px;
  padding:5px 0 10px 0;
  display:block;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family:'Josefin Sans';
  letter-spacing:1px;
}

.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-facebook { color: #FF0000; }
.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-twitter { color:#00ABE3 }
.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-instagram { color:#FFD400 }
.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-pinterest { color:#FF0000 }
.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-google-plus { color:#cb2027 }
.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-flickr { color:#FF57AE }
.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-500px { color:#00ABE3 }
.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-youtube { color:#FF1F25 }
.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-behance { color:#FF57AE }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="sidebar-social">

<ul>
<li>
<a href="URL-HERE" title="Facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
  <span>facebook</span></a></li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Google Plus" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i><span>Google plus</span></a>
</li>
        
<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><span>twitter</span></a>
</li>
        
<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Pinterest" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i><span>Pinterest</span></a>
</li>
        
<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Instagram" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span>Instagram</span></a>
</li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Behance" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i><span>Behance</span></a> 
</li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="flickr" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i><span>Flickr</span></a>
</li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="YouTube" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i><span>Youtube</span></a>
</li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="500px" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-500px"></i><span>500 PX</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!
Can you help me out a bit more?
The icon changes color when a mouse hovers over it. Is there a way to change its color even when mouse is just inside the gray margin?

Comment: ok. I hope this is what you were looking for. if this is, then can you please accept and upvote it. thank you for being patient

Answer (score 1):

Use **CSS Flexbox**. Make your `li a` a flex container using `display: flex` and apply alignment rules, like:

```
.sidebar-social a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Also remove extra margin from `<i>`.

Have a look at the working snippet below:

```css
.sidebar-social {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-social ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

.sidebar-social li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 31.9%;
    margin-bottom: 3px!important;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.sidebar-social a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-social i {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #444444;
}

.sidebar-social a i.fa-facebook:hover { color: #FF0000; }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-twitter:hover { color:#00ABE3 }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-instagram:hover { color:#FFD400 }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-pinterest:hover { color:#FF0000 }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-google-plus:hover { color:#cb2027 }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-flickr:hover { color:#FF57AE }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-500px:hover { color:#00ABE3 }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-youtube:hover { color:#FF1F25 }
.sidebar-social a i.fa-behance:hover { color:#FF57AE }
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>


<div class="sidebar-social">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="URL-HERE" title="Facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span>Facebook</span></a></li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Google Plus" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i><span>Google Plus</span></a>
</li>
        
<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><span>Twitter</span></a>
</li>
        
<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Pinterest" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i><span>Pinterest</span></a>
</li>
        
<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Instagram" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span>Instagram</span></a>
</li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="Behance" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i><span>Behance</span></a> 
</li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="flickr" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i><span>Flickr</span></a>
</li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="YouTube" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i><span>YouTube</span></a>
</li>

<li><a href="URL-HERE" title="500px" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-500px"></i><span>500px</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are good, but maybe not helping you were you get stuck. Also, flexbox is not stellarly well supported yet.

Here's what I would do, stripped of bells & whistles, and I added borders so you see what's going on.

```
body {
font-size: 18px;
} /* Set a base font size of at least 12px, for accessibility */

ul {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
border: solid 1px green;
overflow: hidden;
}

li {
display: block;
width: 8rem; 
/* using rem you can size relatiuve to font size. Easier to make responsive and better accessibility */
height: 8rem;
padding: 1rem;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
border: solid 1px yellow;
}

/* Do not forget hover, active and focus styles for accessibility */
a i,
a span {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
border: solid 1px red;
text-align: center;
}

a i {font-size: 2rem!important;} /* Bootstrap being a penis, override */
a span {font-size: 1rem;}
```

Essentially you use a span around your text, and stack the two like lego's. ;-)

HTH, gl, hf. :)

Answer (score -1):

**Example:**

```
<div class="div class">

    <i class="fas fa-icon"></i> "put icon below the text"

    <h3>Some Text</h3>

    <p>Some text</p>

</div>
```