# CSS Menu layout. How to place text below Icon?

Tags: javascript, css, layout, flexbox

I have a sandbox below. I have set the width of the sidebar to be fixed. I'm trying to make it so that the menu text is below the icon however the text doesn't seem to appear at all when I try to wrap it with div or span.

Would I need to have a flex container?

```
      <Menu.Item key="1" style={{ height: 80 }}>
      <div style={{height: 80, display: "flex", textAlign: "center"}}>
        <Icon type="pie-chart" />
        <span>Option 1</span>
        </div>
      </Menu.Item>
```

[image: Edit upbeat-mirzakhani-hhm7v]

[image: .]

How can I successfully achieve below layout?

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: You can use flex-box to reach this. https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-elgamal-id7mf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @demkovych is it possible to use class names instead of the selector like my example above?

Comment: I don't know ant framework.

Comment: @demkovych thanks dem, I will figure it out from here

Answer (score 0):

Similar is already tried and shown here below
Link : [How do I add Add text below font awesome icon Links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285466/how-do-i-add-add-text-below-font-awesome-icon-links/41285702)
Check if solution helps to you with HTML+CSS trick

Answer (score 0):

```
<Menu.Item key="1" style={{ min-height: 80 }}>
   <div style={{min-height: 80, height: "auto", display: "flex", textAlign: "center"}}>
      <Icon type="pie-chart" style={{display: "block"}}>/>
      <span>Option 1</span>
   </div>
</Menu.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

RESULT:

[image]

Change width value to something greater than 74 like 200.

[image]